# Finding Value Of An Index When Index Not Found

Tags: php

I am migrating a site to a new server.

On the first server the site run fine.

In the new server some file paths are changing do to the `Server_Root_Dir_Path`

I am clearing errors and 2 of the errors are the typical and common

```
Notice: Undefined index: page in /home4/filepath/index.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined variable: admin in /filePAth/libraries.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: theme in /home4/filepath/index.php on line 6
```

My question is...

In this situation I am trying to solve each notice and error.

So I start with the variable and I want to know the value of it so since its undefined on Server B

I go to Server A and `var_dump($admin);`

Is there some type of equivalent on server A to see what `page or theme` are exactly?

This is how they are in the actual files,

```
if ($_GET["page"]=="my_home"){$_GET["page"]="my_handshakes";}



elseif($_COOKIE["theme"]){
```

I realize I could just add `isset` to these but when I do the errors and notice clear but then the page loads blank.

So to be clear,

Is there a way to basically `var_dump` the page or theme on the first server that the site is running perfectly on to see what their values are supposed to be?

Comment: set some default value if the page is not set, so that you will get result as default

Comment: but i think page is supposed to be set to something in order to get the site to load. I dont know what that is so site B wont load.

Comment: Page isset on site A so how can I see what page isset too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you posted, the variable it is looking for is `$_GET["page"]`. "Undefined index" means it found the `$_GET` array, but no item in it with the key `"page"`.

So, firstly, yes, you can `var_dump($_GET["page"])` on your working server, nothing special needed there.

Secondly, though, you should know that `$_GET` represents the query string of the currently loaded page, so unless there is some really ugly code creating fake entries in it, what is actually expected is a URL containing `?page=something`.

Finally, have you actually tried setting the old server to have the same setting of error_reporting as the new one? Since these are notices, it's entirely possible that they've been there all along, but hidden by your settings, and the actual problem with the page is somewhere else altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I used to face this problem the reason was 2 :-

1. The best is to fix them if possible.
2. Try to keep php version >=5.3
3. Disable warning and notices because when i was developing on my localhost warnings were disabled while on live server it was enabled hence i disabled them and it was okay... But keep error reporting on... remember we have different error levels and what i was getting is warning hence i disabled it.

Thanks

Comment: In my question I clearly state that when I clear these errors on site B the page loads blank. How can I see what page `isset` to on site A? IS there some type of equivalent like `var_dump()`